# C# WinForms datagridview row not showing images when form is loaded inside a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, panel

I'm trying to do a conditional image render in datagridview row, but when form with datagridview is displayed inside a panel then image rendering is not working, cells only show default error image.
Without displaying inside a panel everything works well.

[Image of forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zsYZ.png)

Code for conditional rendering:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
            DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageCol);
            imageCol.HeaderText = "ImageStatus";
            imageCol.Name = "ImageStatus";

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int age = int.Parse(row.Cells["age"].Value.ToString());
                if (age > 18)
                {
                    row.Cells["ImageStatus"].Value = new Bitmap(Resources.verfied);
                   
                } else
                {
                    row.Cells["ImageStatus"].Value = new Bitmap(Resources.not_verified);
                }
               
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Since the form is shown *after* the form load event, there are likely no DGV rows to iterate.  You ought not have to iterate all the rows - use the RowPrePaint or CellFormatting event.  And finally, cache those images in variables or an array - you are creating a new unique object each time and likely not disposing of anything which makes you app leak

Comment: Thank you very much! Used RowPrePaint and images are kept in a separate variable in actual production code.